# parse error in mypy when using a basic type hint

Tags: python, mypy

I just installed Mypy tonight for the first time (running in Linux, on a Chromebook).

Mypy is giving me errors when I run `mypy --python-version 3.7 -c "i:int=1"`:

```
test.py:1: error: Parse error before :
```

How can I figure out what is causing this?

EDIT: it appears that the `--python-version 3.7` option isn't working (or doesn't do what I think it does); I get the same error with `--python-version 3.9`. My installed python versions are:

```
ricky@penguin:~$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
ricky@penguin:~$ python3 -V
Python 3.7.3
```

The error persists even when I run Mypy when inside a virtual environment (also version 3.7.3).

Comment: What version of Python is mypy running on?

Comment: @user2357112 i've stared at `mypy --help` and haven't been able to figure out how to determine that (i feel dumb). the system python3 version is 3.7.3 (i'm on a chromebook using the official Linux support)

Comment: I'm not able to repro this issue. What version of mypy are you running? (`mypy --version`). The latest version is 0.701. If you *are* using mypy 0.701, maybe try uninstalling it and installing the interpreted version of it instead? (`pip uninstall mypy`; `pip install --no-binary mypy mypy`). It seems very unlikely, but maybe the compiled version of mypy has a bug that prevents it from working cleanly on chromebooks. It could also be worth running mypy in super-verbose mode just on the off-chance that reveals something interesting (`mypy --python-version 3.7 -c "i:int=1" -v -v -v`).

Comment: @Michael0x2a i will do all of that this evening; i'm sure i have the latest version since i downloaded it fresh. however btw, i did `sudo apt install mypy` rather than `pip install ...`; that shouldn't make a difference, should it?

Comment: @Michael0x2a this might be a clue: on my Windows machine here at work, if i do `mypy --python-version 3.9 -c "i:int=1"`, i get: `mypy: error: failed to find a Python executable matching version (3, 9), perhaps try --python-executable, or --no-site-packages?`. I do NOT get this error on my chromebook; it happily attempts to run the code... Should I open an issue in the repo at this point?

Comment: Installing using `apt` might actually be the problem after all. The mypy core dev team only publishes releases to PyPi, and so there's no guarantee any other third party distributions will be up-to-date. I'd double-check the version before filing a bug. The error you're getting on Windows seems correct to me: your chromebook ought to be giving the same error.

Comment: @Michael0x2a FIXED. it turns out the apt version is way behind: 0.47. version 0.701 works perfectly. thanks for the patient help. i'm a dim bulb sometimes. :)